# Button background setting

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder, uibutton

This question is almost embarrassing to ask, but I can't find the answer in any documentation.

I have a UIButton in a view.  In IB, I set the button's background to a colour.  The original rectangle in the Identity Inspector shows a half-black, half-white rectangle for the button's background.

I can't find anyway to set the background back to the original setting.  Anybody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

John Doner

Comment: Dude, you have asked 12 other questions and accepted none of them as the answer. You really need to work on that before people stop answering you. Marking a response as the answer gives reputation to the answerer and is a way of thanking them, and also lets future readers of the question know what the answer was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Half black, half white means it has an alpha value.

Click on the color, and in the bottom part of the color picker, you can set the alpha. Set it back to 0% to have the original value back.

Comment: Actually, that's reversed: set the alpha to 100% to get your original color back. 0% means completely transparent.

Comment: OK, thanks.  There is a vast amount of knowledge in the "cloud" out there that seems to be very hard to locate in documentation.

John Doner